# CRON - Best way of using a cronjob invoking commands with spaces in it

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I have a cronjob like this:

```
SCRIPTSFOLDER=/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/A\ folder/
*/30 * * * * SCRIPTSFOLDER/getInfo.sh >> SCRIPTSFOLDER/getInfo.out 2>> SCRIPTSFOLDER/getInfo.err
```

I know beforehand that this won't execute because of the `A\ folder`, what is the best workaround to it. 
Also, will the `SCRIPTSFOLDER` variable work?

Answer (score 1):

You could use double quotes, for example:

```
SCRIPTSFOLDER="/mnt/c/Users/User/Documents/A folder"
```

And they use it like this:

```
*/30 * * * * "$SCRIPTSFOLDER/getInfo.sh"
```

But for simplicity I would suggest creating a basic script and then within the script invoke your commands, something like this:

```
*/30 * * * * /path/to/your-script.sh
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought I read somewhere that cronjobs didn't support double quotes.